# Rotated text box for report cover

Tags: rotating, covers

My school has presented me with the following template for report covers, but this only exists in .ppt-format.
I wish to make a LaTeX-version of it, but i am unsure how to create the rotated text boxes and how to place them on the very edge of the paper.

[image]

Comment: I think your university's requirement would make more sense if it were a University of *Arts*; my sympathies that you have to spend your time doing exotic typesetting rather than science and technology. I believe you could build a good, fairly simple, solution using the `xcoffins` package, but I'm sorry, I don't have enough time at the moment to show you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a quick and dirty solution. I just added the elements as shown in your `ppt` sample. I didn't take exact measurements.

I created all elements using `\node` positioning relative to the page's corners or its center or relative to other nodes.

For making an exact copy of the original template i suggest you take measurements of all lengths and extract the right color values as using the correct font faces.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % Rotated boxes on the left
        \node at ($(current page.west)+(0,5)$) [fill=blue!25, rotate=90, anchor=north, minimum height=3cm, text width=5cm, align=left] (pw) {~~~~~\Large Project Work};
        \node [left=0cm of pw, minimum height=3cm, text width=8cm, rotate=90, anchor=east, align=right] {\textbf{NTNU}\\Norwegian University of\\Science and Technology\\Faculty of Engineering Science and Technology\\Departement of Energy and Process Engineering};

        % Title block
        \node at ($(current page.north)+(0,-5)$) (student) {\Large Student (your name)};
        \node [below=.5cm of student] (title) {\Huge Title};
        \node [below=.5cm of title] {Trondheim, MM YYYY};
        \node at ($(current page.center)+(2,-1)$) {\missingfigure[figheight=10cm, figwidth=15cm]{your image here}}; 

        % Ntnu Logo
        \node at ($(current page.south east)+(-2.5,1)$) [text width=4cm] (text) {\textbf{NTNU - Trondheim}\\Norwegian University of Science and Technology};
        \node [left=.5cm of text, rectangle, fill=blue!75!black, rounded corners, minimum size=1.5cm] (bluelogo) {};
        \node at (bluelogo) [rectangle, fill=white, minimum size=.75cm] (whitelogo) {};
        \node at (whitelogo) [circle, fill=blue!75!black, minimum size=.65cm] () {};        
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

Comment: But why use tikz for such a simple layout?

Answer (score 1):

Take the documentclass scrbook; manual: `texdoc scrguiden` on command line. Use the titlepage environment. You need the graphixc package (`texdoc graphixc`), which provides the rotatebox. I'd simply use a picture environment on the titlepage, inside the rotatebox.